# Show calculated Result on top item of bellow items

Tags: java, android

I am trying to **get the result of some calculated values** in recyclerview items **and show it center item**. In my case it requires to run two process onBind Holder that is calculating and showing, is there any way to update adapter without listener like `Click` after loading recyclerview? or any idea? can anyone help me, please? thanks in advance.

for eg: I have 3 items in the list

```
my list in recyclerview  | need calculated result in the center
john    1                        1
tom     0                        4
sam     3                        3



@Override
public void bindViewHolder(final FlexibleAdapter<IFlexible> adapter, final MyViewHolder holder,
                                       final int position,
                                       List<Object> payloads) {
        int[] list = {1,0,3};
        for(int a: list ){
          setCount(a);
        }

// here i need calculated value
    holder.txtCount.setText(String.Valueof(getCount));
```

Comment: Share your code, please

Comment: @Nensil, Thanks. this is my base working of code, full code is more to show here so that it works through out more and more functions.